# Confused about why p tag shows up next to div, if anyone is willing to took through it

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out what I'm doing wrong or what's missing/causing this but if I were to add a p tag under a div it shows up next to the div.

For HTMl I basically have the following:

```css
#container,
#container2,
.container2-info {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#sc1,
#sc2,
#sc3,
#sc4,
#sc5,
#sc6 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: auto;
}

#sc1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#sc2 {
  background-color: slategray;
}

#sc3 {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

#sc4 {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#sc5 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#sc6 {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#sc7 {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.name {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.version {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.changes,
.dl {
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.dl-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="sc1">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc2">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc3">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc4">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc5">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc6">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc7">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Sign Up</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
<p>test</p>
<div id="container2">
  <p style="font-size: 30px;margin-bottom: -10px;" class="container2-info">Above Here</p>
  <p class="container2-info">More text</p>
  <p class="container2-info">Even More text</p>
  <p class="container2-info">Another Text</p>
  <br>
  <img id=img1 src="somepath.jpg">
</div>
<p>test</p>
```

If you look at the images, I want any text I type between `<div id="container"></div>` and `<div id="container2"></div>` to show up between the yellow box with that "Sign Up" button and the text that says "Above Here". I think if you were to load it into documents and view it in the browser, it might be easier to understand what I'm trying to say. The code is incomplete, but it replicates my issue exactly.

Some images that show what I mean:
This is what I don't want: https://prnt.sc/14t6qey
This is what I do want: https://prnt.sc/14t73j3

Comment: This is ***incredibly*** confusing. Can you just add exactly what you've done and have it show the problem? Try adding a code snippet (without your comments in the html) and see if the problem replicates.

Comment: The description of your problem is very confusing. It would be better if you could just post the markup as is. Additionally, for starters, can you verify if your HTML is valid? sometimes if certain tags are not closed correctly, browsers tend to behave very oddly. You can validate your HTML here https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @wazz I essentially redid everything, if you load the html code and css code into a file and view it in a browser, I think it would make a lot more sense what I'm trying to get at. The two screenshots I included would help a lot in getting across what I'm trying to explain. Sorry that it was confusing.

Comment: `div + p { clear:left }`

Answer (score 0):

You can align the whole `body` rather than aligning each container in css

```css
#sc1,
#sc2,
#sc3,
#sc4,
#sc5,
#sc6 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: auto;
}

#sc1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

#sc2 {
  background-color: slategray;
}

#sc3 {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

#sc4 {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#sc5 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#sc6 {
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#sc7 {
  width: 400px;
  float: left;
  height: 125px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.name {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.version {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.changes,
.dl {
  font-style: normal;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.dl-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}


body{
  width:400px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="container" >
  <div id="sc1">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc2">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc3">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc4">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc5">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc6">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="changes">New Changes</button>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Download</a></button>
  </div>
  <div id="sc7">
    <p class="name">Some Text</p>
    <p class="version">Some Text</p>
    <button class="dl"><a class="dl-text" href="some file in a directory">Sign Up</a></button>
  </div>
</div>
<p>test</p>
<div id="container2">
  <p style="font-size: 30px;margin-bottom: -10px;" class="container2-info">Above Here</p>
  <p class="container2-info">More text</p>
  <p class="container2-info">Even More text</p>
  <p class="container2-info">Another Text</p>
  <br>
  <img id=img1 src="somepath.jpg">
</div>
<p>test</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: p tag appears in the same line as div because only 400px of the width is used by div

Comment: That's kind of what I thought, but the issue is that the second div is also 400px in width, so I don't know what's causing that first <p>text</p> to show up next to the div unlike the second <p>text</p>

Comment: but some free space is left as your screen width is greater than 400px so it appears on same line

Comment: that's what I thought except it doesn't explain why the second <p>text</p> after container2, it doesn't explain why that doesn't got on the left, it goes to the next line, unlike the first <p>text</p>